# Given $a + b + c = 20$, find $\max(ab + ac + bc)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Given that $a + b + c = 20$, what's the maximum possible value for $ab +ac + bc$? 
$$\left(a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}\right)$$

I tried following this post, [Evaluating  max(ab+bc+ac)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424722/evaluating-maxabbcac), which lead to:
$ab + bc + ac = 200 - (b - 10)^2 - (c - 10)^2 - bc$, but I couldn't get anywhere afterwards.

Manually trying different numbers lead me to $a = b = 7, c = 6$ with a max result of $133$, but I can't prove it. I assumed for the sum to be the maximum, $a, b, c$ have to be as big as possible, therefore they should be as close to $\frac{20}{3}$ as possible. But is that really the case? If so how can it be proven?

Comment: Hint: use [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality) to get $ab+bc+ca \le 3\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2 = 133.33..$

Comment: @achillehui This sounds very interesting, and I will take a look at it. But I doubt it's the intended way to solve the question since the question comes from a very basic high school contest.

Comment: You can prove that inequality yourself by first showing $ab+bc+ca \le a^2+b^2+c^2$ and then add $2(ab+bc+ca)$ to both sides and divide by $3$....

Comment: @achillehui Oh yeah, I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Solution :

$a+b+c=20$
$(a+b+c)^2=400$
$a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=400$
$X=(ab+bc+ca)=200-(a^2+b^2+c^2)/2$

We want to maximize X which occurs when $Y=(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ is minimized.
When $a<b$ , we can increase $a$ by $\delta$ while decreasing $b$ by $\delta$ (keeping total sum Constant) , which decreases $Y$.

When $a>b$ , we can decrease $a$ by $\delta$ while increasing $b$ by $\delta$ (keeping total sum Constant) , which decreases $Y$.

Likewise , $b<c$ , $b>c$ , $c<a$ , $c>a$ can all be adjusted to "Equality" to minimize $Y$.
We can not adjust further when we have attained "Equality" for the 3 variables.

In other words , $Y$ is minimum when $a=b=c=20/3$
In that Case , $X=3(20/3)(20/3)=400/3=133.333$ is the maximum , when $a,b,c$ are real numbers. When these are Integers, this value is the upper bound.

We can take nearest Integers $(a,b,c)=(7,7,6)$ to get the Integral maximum $7\times7+7\times6+6\times7=133$.

Comment: Note that $X = 133.33$ cannot be achieved, as the domain is the integers, not all real numbers. Thus, it is not the maximum (and just an upper bound).

Comment: I have added your valid Point , @CalvinLin , thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems to be have been answered in the comments, here's an algorithmic approach:
Keep one variable constant (say $b$).
$$\max(ab+bc+ac)$$
$$\max(b(a+c)+ac)$$
$a+c$ is constant since we have kept $b$ to be constant. Let $a+c = k$:
$$\max(bk+a(k-a))$$Thus, if one variable is kept constant, the maximum occurs when the other two are equal (or as close as possible).
Suppose you have an initial solution $a_0,b_0,c_0$ such that $a_0+b_0+c_0 = 20$ but $a_0b_0+b_0c_0+a_0c_0$ is not maximum. Replace both $a_0$ and $c_0$ by $a_0+c_0\over 2$ (if $a_0$ and $c_)$ have opposite parities, then replace $a_0$ by $a_0+c_0+1\over 2$and $c_0$ by $a_0+c_0-1\over 2$) and call them $a_1$ and $c_1$. Now do this process with $a_1$ and $b_0$, then with $b_1$ and $c_1$, then with $a_2$ and $c_2$ and so on.
The sum remains the same at each algorithm step, but $ab+bc+ac$ increases. 
We know that after every step, the value must increase, however, there exists a maximum (since there are only finite possible values for $a,b,c$). Thus, when we reach the maximum, the algorithm will produce no new triplet (it may swap values).

Thus, the maximum will be such that there will be no natural number between any two variables (otherwise replace both of them by that number(s) and we get a more optimal solution)
It is easy to see that two variables must be odd and one even otherwise all even. If they are all even, then there exists a natural number between two of them, which is more optimal than the previous solution. Thus the maximal solution will be 2 odd numbers and one even. If the two odd numbers are not equal, then there exists a number between them, which makes the solution more optimal. Thus they are equal. If the even number is not adjacent to them, then there exists a number between them, which makes the solution more optimal.
Thus, the solution consists of $2$ equal odd numbers and an adjacent even number. Only $\color{green}{(7,7,6)}$ satisfies this.

Answer (score 1):

Define two vectors on Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$ equipped with the standard Euclidean inner product:

$$\vec{v} = (a, b, c) $$
$$\vec{u} = (b, c, a) $$

Then the inner product of these two vectors is given by:

$$\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u} \rangle = |\vec{v}||\vec{u}|\cos{(\sphericalangle(\vec{u},\vec{v})}) = ab+bc+ca = ab+ac+bc$$

Where the last equality is simply due to rearrangement of the terms.

We begin by maximizing the inner product $\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u} \rangle$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Since the inner product is clearly maximized when $\cos(\sphericalangle(\vec{u},\vec{v})) = 1$, we have:

$$ \max{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u} \rangle} = |\vec{v}||\vec{u}|$$

Which in components reads:

$$ \max{\langle \vec{v}, \vec{u} \rangle} = ab+bc+ca = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+c^2+a^2}=a^2+b^2+c^2$$
$$ab+bc+ca=a^2+b^2+c^2$$

Now, the above maximizes $ab+bc+ca$ over $\mathbb{R}$, but since we want to maximize it over $\mathbb{N}$ we must find the actual maximal *value* in $\mathbb{R}$ to later derive the maximal value in $\mathbb{N}$. We add $2(ab+bc+ca)$ to both sides of the last equality and, applying our condition $a+b+c=20$ we obtain:

$$3(ab+bc+ca) = (a+b+c)^2 = 400$$

$$ ab+bc+ca = \frac{400}{3}$$

So having found that $\frac{400}{3}$ maximizes the LHS over $\mathbb{R}$ it follows that $\lfloor\frac{400}{3}\rfloor=133$ maximizes the LHS over $\mathbb{N}$.

It remains to find $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy both the above maximization condition and the condition: $a+b+c=20$.

We verify that for $(a,b,c)=(7,7,6)$ we indeed have the latter, and also:

$$ ab+bc+ca = 7\cdot7 + 7\cdot6 + 6\cdot7 = 133 $$

**Thank you @CalvinLin for pointing out and helping me fix a serious mistake in the final part of the original answer!**

Comment: 1/ Maximizing over the reals and approximating to the nearest integer value might not be the same as maximizing over the integers. (It might be true if you show some further "niceness" condition).  2/ One can easily obtain $ ab + bc + ca \leq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ without the detour to inner products, so what is the value of doing so?

Comment: @CalvinLin -- the value was showing when $ab+bc+ca$ obtains its maximum value. Since for $a+b+c=20$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a very small number of possibilities that approximate this, it is easy by inspection to then find which of them maximizes the expression over the naturals. Also note that the OP asked in particular: "...therefore they should be as close to 20/3 as possible. But is that really the case? If so how can it be proven?". And I tried to address that. Showing $ab+bc+ca \leq a^2+b^2+c^2$ is not identical to showing that the RHS maximizes the LHS

Comment: 1/ You're not showing when $ab+bc+ca$ obtains it's maximum value. You are merely showing $ ab+bc+ca \leq a^2+b^2+c^2$. It achieves the maximum value only if $a=b=c$, which it does not. For example, $ab+bc+ca < 7^2+7^2+6^2$ (where this value cannot be achieved over the integer)    $\quad$  2/ So what if you optimized for $ ab + bc + ca \approx a^2 +b^2 +c^2$? That doesn't mean that we've achieved the maximum of the LHS, because the RHS changes so much. EG In what way have you shown that (say) $ ab + bc + ca < 150 $? Note for example, that $ 10^2 + 10^2 + 0 ^2 = 200$.

Comment: Arguably, all that you have is $ \max (ab + bc + ca) \leq \max (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = 400$. However, that doesn't seem helpful to the problem.

Comment: @CalvinLin -- I'm not certain, I'm really trying to see if this is totally useless or not. Suppose the next step after the last is add $2(ab+bc+ca)$ to both sides of the equation. You then obtain $3(ab+bc+ca)=400$ using the condition $a+b+c=20$. Isn't that a sufficient condition for optimizing $ab+bc+ca$? That is, finding $a,b,c$ which make this expression nearest $400/3$? (Again, the OP wanted to know why it's true that indeed it must be closest to this value...)

Comment: @CalvinLin -- Please don't get me wrong I am thankful for your criticism, I only want to see if this method can be of any value or not

Comment: That "next step" significantly (to me) changes what you have, and we now have a  "one-line" solution:  $ 3(ab+bc+ca) \leq  (a+b+c)^2 = 400$ so the max over the integers is indeed $133$.  $\quad$ It sidesteps the issues I raised (because those are not needed in this argument).

Comment: @CalvinLin -- I am not trying to sidestep that the proof has an issue, I am only trying to understand the issue. Now, supposing we are still over the reals then this is a strict equality that $3(ab+bc+ca)=400$ after adding $2(ab+bc+ca)$ to both sides. That is, over the reals $ab+bc+ca$ is maximized at $400/3$. I am asking whether if I add that detail to my answer if that would make it helpful.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between A/ The max over the reals occurs at $(a, b, c)$, so the max over the integers occurs at $ \approx ( \lfloor a \rfloor, \lfloor b \rfloor, \lfloor c \rfloor)$ and B/ The max over the reals is $ f(a, b, c)$, so the maximum possible integer value is $ \lfloor f(a, b, c) \rfloor$? That is the distinction between the 2 approaches. The second is valid, the first isn't.

Comment: @CalvinLin -- Yes! I do understand and I thank you for pointing that out. So now since I can proceed to show that $f(a,b,c) = ab+bc+ca$ is maximized at $400/3$ over $\mathbb{R}$ it also follows that $f(a,b,c)$ is maximized at $\lfloor{400/3}\rfloor=133$ over $\mathbb{N}$, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was going for.

Comment: @CalvinLin - Thank you very much, I've edited my answer. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain the error.